# Trigger AJAX from PHP

Tags: php, ajax

So this is kind of a strange question and you may think it is the other way around but here it comes.

I make use of a framework called Laravel. Not that it makes any difference but i thought it is worth mentioning. On this framework i have an web-application which makes it possible to rate pictures in albums.

The pictures that are being uploaded are coming in from an android application. The picture is made from a phone which converts it to base64 and sends it to the web-application. The input that it sends is being received by a controller action in my web-application.

The above does work! But now i want to trigger some kind of event in PHP when the controller action is begin used. So when a picture is being uploaded, the user that uses the web-application sees there is a new picture added to the album.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your best bet might be to look into uploading your image asynchronously and then run a callback function that updates the page on success.

Comment: But how do i upload the image asynchronous when the Android asynctask requires an url? I do not believe this is possible from the application side so it must be handled on the web-application side. The only trigger for the web-application is the controller function which handles the base64 string that is being send from the Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could be inspired by this website and drop a bar at the top of the web app notifying the user of a change.

Or create a reload button that lights up and indicates the number of changes.  When the user clicks that button, the gallery could be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Setup up a poller to check every X seconds for new images. And if there is a new image, display it.

This is how stackoverflow works for new answers. If you inspect the console tab in Firebug, you will see it poll every 30 seconds(ish).

Example (using jQuery):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('/check-for-images', function(data) {
        if (data instanceof Array) {
            $.each(data, function(i, image) {
                $('<img/>').attr('src', image).appendTo('#container');
            }
        }
    });
}, 30000);
```

PHP:

```
$result = query('SELECT name FROM images WHERE date > :lastUpdated', $lastUpdated);
echo json_encode(fetchArray($results));
```

Comment: Thank you, i already knew this solution But i don't think it is a pretty one. A solution i do love is websockets, but it does require a nodejs server or something. And i only have an Apache server with PHP.

Comment: Ratchet is a web socket library for php. Just check compatibility with web sockets and the phones that use your application.

Comment: @Jack I don't see how not using this ***standard*** approach is not acceptable. What's not "pretty" about it?

Comment: Because it keeps checking for new database entries even if there is none. And a websocket updates only if there is a new entry.

But if there isn't another way to do this, i have to use your way. I just don't like unneeded requests.